# Cannot load themes with AngularJS Material

Tags: css, angularjs, themes, angular-material, angularjs-material

I have installed Angular (1) Material (v.1.1.5) via NuGet in my Visual Studio project and referenced it following their guide:

```
<script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<link href="content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="content/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

From their guide:

> If you're using the Angular CLI, you can add this to your styles.css:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

> Alternatively, you can just reference the file directly. This would
>   look something like:

```
<link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

NuGet won't install the prebuilt themes .css files and I cannot find them on the Net. Or am I simply doing something wrong? Am I missing something? Should the prebuilt themes be part of the *angular-material.min.css* file?

EDIT:
@Edric:
I have already defined my mdThemeProvider:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl" md-theme="ccc" md-theme-watch="true">
```

&

```
var myApp = angular.module("MyApp", ['ngAnimate', 'ngAria', 'ngMessages', 'ngMaterial', 'ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']);

rcaApp.config(function ($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('ccc')
      .primaryPalette('pink')
      .accentPalette('orange')
      .dark();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the documentation for [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io). You should be looking at the docs for [AngularJS Material](https://material.angularjs.org) instead.

Anyways, here's the correct way to define a theme using `$mdThemeProvider`:

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
    .config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
        $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
            .primaryPalette('pink')
            .accentPalette('orange');
});
```

[More info on theming](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme)

Comment: I tried to paste my $mdThemeProvider code in this CodePen https://codepen.io/kyleledbetter/pen/gbQOaV and it works as it should, so I tried to use the references from the CodePen, but still no luck.

Comment: @Tomo Did you completely remove the reference to `indigo-pink.css`?

Comment: therre's no indigo-pink.css, I didn't remove anything.

Comment: What I meant is that did you remove the line `link href="node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">`?

Comment: I don't have no node_modules and no indigo-pink.css, because the NuGet installer won't create them. I mean, even the `$mdThemingProvider.theme('ccc').dark()` won't work.